# name resolution: host command works, but not ping

Tags: networking, dns, resolv.conf

This question as a lot of duplicate, but none of them applies to my setup. This baffles me, as my setup is relatively simple:

**Setup**

I have no `mdns` in my `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
# cat /etc/nsswitch.conf  | grep hosts
hosts:          files dns
```

My `/etc/hosts` is pristine from ubuntu.

I have a `dnsmasq` on port 127.0.0.1:53, but this is not so important as I figured with `tcpdump` that no queries are actually sent to dnsmasq when the resolution actually fails.

The problem probably lies around here:

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
domain .
```

The `domain .` is important to me as I do not want to look for `www.localdomain` when I'm doing name resolution on `www`.

This exact setup is working on another computer.

**The actual issue**

```
# host www
172.128.0.170
# ping www
ping: unknown host www
```

I have to had that:

- with `host`: I get packets on `lo` device on port 53, asking for resolution to `dnsmasq`. So I get a line in `dnsmasq`'s log file... etc...
- with `ping`: I get NO PACKETS on `lo` device, so obviously, no line in dnsmasq log.

Any new hostname without dots (deliberately not valid hostname) would give the same behavior (no packets sent with `ping`, packets sent with `host`). Of course the resolution fails for both of them.

**Any new hostname with dots works correctly.**

This works on another server not having the same `libc6` (Ubuntu 15.10, `libc6` is `2.21-0ubuntu4.1`). It fails on Ubuntu 12.04.1 with `libc6` `2.15-0ubuntu10.10`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution myself so that `ping` works correctly again. But no answer about why this doesn't work on the computer. So I won't accept this solution, but this might help people having the same issue:

The behavior is due to the line `domain .` in `/etc/resolv.conf` somehow not behaving the same between both of the version of `libc6`.

I can achieve what I was looking for by forcing an unexistent local search (which is not very elegant, but works), by replacing `domain .` by `search doesnotexist`.

Then magically, all works as expected, but I get additional spurious DNS requests being sent to `dnsmasq` before (it tries first to resolv `www.doesnotexist` which fails, then tries `www` which exists.

This setup was required in my configuration as `www` and `www.myactualdomainname` and pointing to different IP.